# ILSVRC2012 validation ground_truth labels index not matching pretrained networks index

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lasagne, imagenet, pre-trained-model

I'm currently using VGG-S pretrained convolutional neural network provided by Lasagne library, from the following [link](https://github.com/Lasagne/Recipes/blob/master/examples/ImageNet%20Pretrained%20Network%20(VGG_S).ipynb).

I downloaded the validation dataset of ILSVRC2012 in order to do a classification task, but I saw that the ground truth values found in the file ILSVRC2012_devkit_t12_v2/data/ILSVRC2012_validation_ground_truth.txt didn't match at all the output values of the VGG-S network (softmax values).

For example: the last image ILSVRC2012_val_00050000.JPEG which is clearly a Llama, vgg-s outputs label n°355 (llama), while the ground truth label found in the file is n° 186 (Norwich terrier).

The index-to-label is the same as this [one](https://gist.github.com/maraoz/388eddec39d60c6d52d4).

Can anyone please tell me where I'm wrong ?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8):

The ground truth system you are using is developed by caffe group, where is different from Imagenet standard groundtruth indexing system.

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/data/ilsvrc12

Replace your groungtruth with val.txt.

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, I found out that VGG convolutional networks used a different class order according to this [note](https://gist.github.com/ksimonyan/fd8800eeb36e276cd6f9#note)

The validation ground truth labels that were used can be downloaded from 
[here](http://dl.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/caffe_ilsvrc12.tar.gz)